# Should I use different unit-testing framework for client and server code?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, mocha.js

My client & server code both are written in javascript. Client uses AngularJS and server uses Node.js framework.

After some googling, I had settled with **Jasmine** for client code unit testing and **Mocha** for server code unit-testing.

But now the question has come up why use different frameworks for testing? So should I instead use Jasmine for both client and server? Or mocha for both? Or something else altogether?

Also please mention a reason why should I go with so-and-so framework.

Comment: I'd stick with Jasmine for both. Note that this question is likely to be closed because it is opinion based.

Comment: It's always better to simplify. Use the same framework for both.

Comment: @helpermethod: I am looking for more than just opinion. A reason for going with one or other framework

Comment: I can’t help with the decision about which framework because it is a matter of taste in the end. However, a good reason to use the same framework for both is less context switches. For the same reason, I’d also consider using Browserify, because it allows you to write the same style of JavaScript for browsers and node.

Answer (score 0):

you should always use best tool for the job. of course you should also think about the cost of maintenance of many different tools. but this cost is rather small for those tools. so if you have technical reasons for using those two and you can defend this decision then there is absolutely nothing wrong with using different testing frameworks